# groupby and apply on two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns: `key1, key2, document`.  All three columns are text fields with the size of `document` ranging from 50 characters to 5000 characters.  I identify a *vocabulary* based on minimum frequency from the set of documents for each `(key1, key2)`  for which I am using `scikit-learn` `CountVectorizer` and setting `min_df`.   I am able to do this using `df.groupby[['key1','key2']]['document'].apply(vocab).reset_index()` where `vocab` is a function in which I compute and return the vocabulary (as defined above) as a set.

Now, I would like to use these vocabularies (one set for each `key1, key2`), to filter the corresponding documents so that each document only has words which are in its vocabulary.  I would appreciate any help I can get with this part.

Sample data

```
Input

key1 | key2 | document
 aa  | bb   | He went home that evening. Then he had soup for dinner.
 aa  | bb   | We want to sit down and eat dinner
 cc  | mm   | Sometimes people eat in a restaurant
 aa  | bb   | The culinary skills of that chef are terrible.  Let us not go there.
 cc  | mm   | People go home after dinner and try to sleep.


Vocabulary - not using counts for the purpose of this example

key1 | key2 | vocab
 aa  | bb   | {went, evening, sit, down, culinary, chef, dinner}
 cc  | mm   | {people, restaurant, home, dinner, sleep}

Result - only use words from corresponding vocab in document

key1 | key2 | document
 aa  | bb   | went evening dinner
 aa  | bb   | sit down dinner
 cc  | mm   | people restaurant
 aa  | bb   | culinary chef
 cc  | mm   | people home dinner sleep
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample - 5 rows with expected output?

Comment: Added sample data. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use first [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) for add column `vocab` to first `DataFrame`:

```
import re

df = df.groupby[['key1','key2']]['document'].apply(vocab).reset_index()
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['key1','key2'], how='left')

#another theoretical solution
#df['vocab'] = df.groupby[['key1','key2']]['document'].transform(vocab)
```

Then extract all words by [`findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html), `re.I` is for ignore case and last remove column `vocab`:

```
df['document'] = df['document'].str.findall('\w+', flags=re.I)
```

Last get intersection between `set`s and convert to strings by [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['document'] = df.apply(lambda x: set(x['document']) & x['vocab'], axis=1).str.join(' ')
df = df.drop('vocab', axis=1)
print (df)
  key1 key2                  document
0   aa   bb       evening went dinner
1   aa   bb           sit down dinner
2   cc   mm         restaurant people
3   aa   bb             chef culinary
4   cc   mm  home people sleep dinner
```

Comment: Jezrael, can you check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48396321/how-to-merge-two-dataframes-based-on-a-column-in-pandas