# how to merge two dataframes based on a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have two data frames,

```
 df1=pd.DataFrame({"Req":["Req 1","Req 2","Req 3"],"Count":[1,2,1]})        
    Req     Count
0   Req 1   1
1   Req 2   2
2   Req 3   1
```

`df2=pd.DataFrame({"Req":["Req 1","Req 2"],"Count":[0,1]})`

```
    Req    Count
0   Req 1   0
1   Req 2   1
```

I am trying to merge these df's based on "Req" column

My desired output is,

```
    Req    total  from_1 from_2
    Req 1   1       1     0
    Req 2   3       2     1
    Req 3   1       1     0
```

I tried `pd.merge(df1, df2, on = "Req", )` but it is not giving my desired output, please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: Use `concat` and `groupby`: `pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('Req').sum()`

Comment: how about the other columns

Comment: That's why I said *Hint* :). It's actually the easy part just append them to the dataframe. (you already have the values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with left join, replace `NaN`s, rename columns and last add new column with `assign`:

```
df = (pd.merge(df1, df2, on = "Req", how='left')
        .fillna(0)
        .rename(columns={'Count_x':'from_1','Count_y':'from_2'})
        .assign(total=lambda x: x['from_1'] + x['from_2'])
      )
print (df)
   from_1    Req  from_2  total
0       1  Req 1     0.0    1.0
1       2  Req 2     1.0    3.0
2       1  Req 3     0.0    1.0
```